# No Wifi Adapter Found before booting into Windows 10 and rebooting back to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wireless, 20.04, windows-10

I have a dual boot setup of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I am able to connect to WiFi in Windows 10 but Ubuntu settings says "WiFi adapter not found". But a strange thing always happens. When I boot Windows 10 first then restart and boot Ubuntu, I can connect to WiFi. But listen when I boot Windows 10, then shut down and boot Ubuntu, again no WiFi adapters found. In simple words restarting from Windows 10 and then to Ubuntu (WiFi Works Fine) but shutting down Windows 10 and booting Ubuntu (WiFi Won't Work). Whenever I have to use Internet on Ubuntu I have to boot Windows 10 first and restart(Not Shut Down) and boot back to Ubuntu to use Internet. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

This is the output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:69:95:ab:80:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This is the output of lspci -k

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    DeviceName: Intel(R) HD Graphics Device
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Device
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Intel(R) High Definition Audio Device
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. IT8892E PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 10)
```

No output for second command you mentioned.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a` (shows if the device is recognized), `rfkill list` (shows if the device is disabled via a physical switch) and `lspci -k` (shows all (PCI) devices and if the kernel module is loaded)

Comment: I have added the output of commands as you said

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Boot feature.

Comment: It is already disabled by me.